# Scroll bars appear on Android HTC 1 M8

Tags: trigger.io

Testing my app on multiple platforms and have run into a problem on the HTC 1 M8 . The app functions fine but the app screen size causes scroll bars to appear and the app doesnt scale to fit. I would have expected this on a smaller screen but nit a large one. We dont see this problem on any other devices we have to test. Tried setting the app to full screen with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

In case any Trigger newbies like me run into a case where they have a similar issue, my problem was related to how I had my div's width defined and the nesting.